# ln -fFs does not update symlink

Tags: macos, command-line, symlink

I have two directories newdir and otherdir and would like to update a symlink, that initially pointed to otherdir to newdir.

When I run:

```
> ln -s otherdir symlink
```

I see a symlink:

```
> ls -al symlink
symlink -> otherdir
```

When I run:

```
> ln -sFf newdir symlink
```

I would expect symlink -> newdir, but I see the old link when I run:

```
> ls -al symlink
symlink -> otherdir
```

And I also noticed that a new symlink exists:

```
> ls -al symlink/newdir
symlink/newdir -> newdir
```

Is there a way to prevent ln from interpreting the destination path as parent directory ?
Or is the only way to prevent this from happening to remove the link first ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the -h option:

> ```
> -h    If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow it. 
>       This is most useful with the -f option, to replace a symlink 
>       which may point to a directory.
> ```

```
$ ln -shf newdir symlink
$ ls -al symlink
symlink -> newdir
```